# ng test does not detect file has been saved via vscode

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, angular-cli

I run `ng test` then I modify my spec files using VScode and hit `ctrl+s` but the tests are not rerun. But when I do a `ctrl+s` in sublime text the tests are correctly rerun. What can I do to fix this behavior in VScode

Comment: Maybe you should 'ng build' before 'ng test'

Comment: I think the problem is that vscode is not sending the proper signal when saving a file

Comment: Did you tried doing build before test again?